# Calculating Ema crossover distance

Tags: pine-script

I need to calculate the distance of previous Ema crossover interms of bars.
Following is the simple code. It is not giving the value interms of bars.
can someone help resolving it ?

```
MACross_Dist_Down() =>
    ema50 = ema(close,50)
    ema200 = ema(close,200)
    dist= 0
    for i=1 to 200
        if (ema50[1]<ema200[1])
            dist := dist + i    
    dist
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
//@version=4
study(title="distance", overlay=true)

ema50       = ema(close,  50)
ema200      = ema(close, 200)

crossed     = cross(ema50, ema200)
distance    = barssince(crossed)

plotchar(distance, "distance", "")

plot(ema50,  color=color.green)
plot(ema200, color=color.blue)
```

Finding the n-th crossing:

```
//@version=4
study(title="distance", overlay=true)

var nth_most_recent_occurance = input(0, "show distance to nth most recent occurrance", input.integer, minval=0)

var int[]   occurrences     = array.new_int(na)

f_barssince_occurrence(_n) =>
    n = nz(_n)
    if array.size(occurrences) >= n+1
        distance = bar_index - array.get(occurrences, n)
    else
        -1

ema50       = ema(close,  50)
ema200      = ema(close, 200)

if cross(ema50, ema200)
    array.unshift(occurrences, bar_index)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(array.size(occurrences)-1) + " occurrances\n\nDistance to " + tostring(nth_most_recent_occurance) + " nd/th\nmost recent occurrance =\n" + tostring(f_barssince_occurrence(nth_most_recent_occurance)) + " bars" )

plot(ema50,  color=color.green)
plot(ema200, color=color.blue)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I didnt know about the barsince function. It gives the bars since it happened last time. Is there a way to find  1 st cross distance , 2 cross distance and so on ?

Comment: Updated my answer with the code to do that.